# openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process in visual code studio

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning nodeJS and getting error

> OpenSSL config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process.

Please help me to solve it. 
I followed this article-
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17261
 but still facing error--

Comment: Please read the question posting guidelines before you ask a question. You need to describe and explain more, abstract questions tend to go unanaswered/ignored by the community.

Comment: Ok Sir,  I am learning nodeJS. Could you help ???

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and reformat your question.

Comment: thank you, I got what I was doing. Thanks a lot.